# java-how to specify the path to a file that i have stored along with source code

Tags: java, file, filepath

I am trying to get the path to a file named "policy.local" which I have stored in /com/package/

I want to specify the path to the above file from a class named "com.package.class". (So this class and the file are in the same folder)... How do I specify the path to the policy.local file, in the java code of class com.package.class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your class and the file (resource) are in the same package, you can get at it with:

```
getClass().getResource("policy.local")
```

If the class and the resource are not in the same package, you will want to use:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/package/policy.local");
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way: create an empty class (with no methods and fields) in the package "/com/package/" if this package doesn't contain any classes, or use any of them, if they are present.
Then do the next:

```
ClassName.class.getResource("policy.local").toString()
```

This will give you a form of an absolute path of your file, something like this:

```
file:/C:/sandbox/xxx/com/package/policy.local
```